# Paypal Sandbox Api Validation Error?

Tags: php, paypal

So I'm playing around with the Paypal Sandbox and I just implemented Credit card transactions. I followed the Paypal Dev example closely but it seems to continuously return an error. I have tried multiple credit cards. Everything was working correctly before  I addec direct credit card transactions.

```
<?php
    use PayPal\Api\Payer;
    use PayPal\Api\Details;
    use PayPal\Api\Amount;
    use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
    use PayPal\Api\Payment;
    use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
    use PayPal\Api\CreditCard;
    use PayPal\Api\FundingInstrument;
    use PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException;

    require 'protected/extensions/paypal/src/start.php';

    $payer = new Payer();
    $details = new Details();
    $amount = new Amount();
    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $payment = new Payment();
    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $card = new CreditCard();

    $card->setType("visa")
        ->setNumber("4214024046137679")
        ->setExpireMonth("03")
        ->setExpireYear("2020")
        // ->setCvv2("012")
        ->setFirstName("asdf")
        ->setLastName("asdf");

    $fi = new FundingInstrument();
    $fi->setCreditCard($card);
    //PAYER
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("credit_card")
     ->setFundingInstruments(array($fi));

    //Details
    //acutal prices(20 dollars is a test)

    //Amount
    $details->setShipping(0.0)
        ->setSubtotal(20.00);

    $amount->setCurrency("CAD")
        ->setTotal(20.00)
        ->setDetails($details);

    //Transaction
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
      ->setDescription('Membership');

    //Payment
    $payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

    try{
      $payment->create($api);
      $currentId = Yii::app()->user->getId();

      $transactionHash = $payment->getId();
      // $_SESSION['transactionId'] = $transactionHash;

      $update = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
      ->update('member', array(
        'transactionId'=> $transactionHash,
        ), 'id=:id', array(':id'=> $currentId));

      var_dump($payment->create($api));

    } catch(PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex){
      echo $ex->getData();
    }

    // $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

    // $redirectUrl = $payment->getHref();
    // header('Location: ' . $approvalUrl);
    ?>
```

This is the error it is returning:

> {"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"payer.funding_instruments[0].credit_card.number","issue":"Value is invalid"},{"field":"payer.funding_instruments[0].credit_card.number","issue":"Must be numeric"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"d25b7c74793c9"}

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace the below code and run as it is(just to check), it looks like you have updated with few lines of code using `yii`,required a file and added classes.

```
<?php

// # CreatePaymentSample
//
// This sample code demonstrate how you can process
// a direct credit card payment. Please note that direct 
// credit card payment and related features using the 
// REST API is restricted in some countries.
// API used: /v1/payments/payment

require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\CreditCard;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\FundingInstrument;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

// ### CreditCard
// A resource representing a credit card that can be
// used to fund a payment.

$card = new CreditCard();
  $card->setType("visa")
        ->setNumber("4214024046137679")
        ->setExpireMonth("03")
        ->setExpireYear("2020")
        // ->setCvv2("012")
        ->setFirstName("asdf")
        ->setLastName("asdf");

// ### FundingInstrument
// A resource representing a Payer's funding instrument.
// For direct credit card payments, set the CreditCard
// field on this object.
$fi = new FundingInstrument();
$fi->setCreditCard($card);

// ### Payer
// A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
// For direct credit card payments, set payment method
// to 'credit_card' and add an array of funding instruments.
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("credit_card")
    ->setFundingInstruments(array($fi));

// ### Itemized information
// (Optional) Lets you specify item wise
// information
$item1 = new Item();
$item1->setName('test SSL')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice('7.50');
$item2 = new Item();
$item2->setName('Granola bars')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(5)
    ->setPrice('2.00');

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item1, $item2));

// ### Additional payment details
// Use this optional field to set additional
// payment information such as tax, shipping
// charges etc.
$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping('1.20')
    ->setTax('1.30')
    ->setSubtotal('17.50');

// ### Amount
// Lets you specify a payment amount.
// You can also specify additional details
// such as shipping, tax.
$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency("USD")
    ->setTotal("20.00")
    ->setDetails($details);

// ### Transaction
// A transaction defines the contract of a
// payment - what is the payment for and who
// is fulfilling it. 
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItemList($itemList)
    ->setDescription("Payment description");

// ### Payment
// A Payment Resource; create one using
// the above types and intent set to sale 'sale'
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

// ### Create Payment
// Create a payment by calling the payment->create() method
// with a valid ApiContext (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
// The return object contains the state.
try {
    $payment->create($api);
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
    echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($ex->getData());
    exit(1);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Direct Credit card payments</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Created payment:
        <?php echo $payment->getId();?>
    </div>
    <pre><?php var_dump($payment->toArray());?></pre>
    <a href='../index.html'>Back</a>
</body>
</html>
```